# Overlapping Folder Tab appearance

Tags: html, css, tabs

I am trying to recreate the tab appearance below. I was trying to use the `:before` and `:after` psuedo-elements, following [this snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/u6r9tqvm/4/), but overlapping them wasn't making sense. I am using React.js as well, but I was hoping I could accomplish this with just CSS/HTML. What would be the simplest way to achieve this?

**Current code:**

```css
.tab-list {
  border-bottom: 1.5px solid #4EBDE5;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.tab-list-item {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tab-list-item:hover {
  background-color: #4EBDE5;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.tab-list-active {
  border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;
  background-color: #4EBDE5;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<ol class="tab-list">
  <li class="tab-list-item tab-list-active">Name</div>
  <li class="tab-list-item">Name</div>
  <li class="tab-list-item">Name</div>
</ol>
```

**Desired appearance:**
[image]
[image: example-tabs]

Comment: what is the criterion that makes the first and last one to be different?

Comment: @aleberguer I am not sure exactly what you mean, like `tab-list-active`?

Comment: I mean, the active tab is above the other two, I just wonder on how it will look if for example the active is the last one, how is the overlapping between two siblings inactive tabs.

Comment: @aleberguer added another view for it, does that help?

Comment: Probably need to use javascript, with z-index

Comment: Sounds about right, thanks @AstroBoyR

Comment: Try using Booleans and seeing if one is open, then toggle the class so that it it shown, and if any others have the open class, then change it to closed.

Comment: Okay I will build this and report back, ty! @AstroBoyR